# База данных в состоянии suspect

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Пользовательская база в состоянии suspect. Что можно сделать: как сохранить данные и получить к ним доступ?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться sp_resetstatus.

Answer (score 1):

```
EXEC sp_resetstatus [YourDatabase];
ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabase] SET EMERGENCY
DBCC checkdb([YourDatabase])
ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabase] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
DBCC CheckDB ([YourDatabase], REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabase] SET MULTI_USER
```